# MPI_Scatter segmentation fault with malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

Can you explain why this code works perfectly fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} point;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  MPI_Datatype mpi_point;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &mpi_point);
  MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_point);


  point local[2];

  if(rank==0)
  {
    point *buf;
    buf = malloc(10*sizeof(point));
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        buf[i].x= (double)i;
        buf[i].y= (double)i+i;
    }
    MPI_Scatter(buf, 2, mpi_point, &local, 2, mpi_point, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    free(buf);
  }
  else
  {
    point *buf = NULL;
    MPI_Scatter(buf, 2, mpi_point, &local, 2, mpi_point, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  printf("Hello, process %d has points: 1-> %f %f 2-> %f %f\n", rank, local[0].x, local[0].y, local[1].x, local[1].y);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

and this one below doesn't work? A lot of error output ending with `segmentation fault`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} point;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  MPI_Datatype mpi_point;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &mpi_point);
  MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_point);


  point *local;

  if(rank==0)
  {
    point *buf;
    buf = malloc(10*sizeof(point));
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        buf[i].x= (double)i;
        buf[i].y= (double)i+i;
    }
    MPI_Scatter(buf, 2, mpi_point, &local, 2, mpi_point, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    free(buf);
  }
  else
  {
    point *buf = NULL;
    local = malloc(2*sizeof(point));
    MPI_Scatter(buf, 2, mpi_point, &local, 2, mpi_point, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  printf("Hello, process %d has points: 1-> %f %f 2-> %f %f\n", rank, local[0].x, local[0].y, local[1].x, local[1].y);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The only difference is that `local` in one case is defined as a vector "directly" and in the other one it's a pointer and then I do the `malloc`. Shouldn't it be the same thing? Both of them are allocated in the stack with the same dimension, so how is it possible that the one with `malloc` doesn't work?

Comment: could it be that MPI_Scatter dereferences the pointer? if so, that could be the cause. for (rank == 0),you send &local which is a pointer is not pointing to an allocated area in the memory.

Comment: You should use `local`, not `&local`! Also, you must provide `local` memory for the root. Where in your code is it *defined as a vector "directly"*?

Comment: In your second example, you should either `local=malloc(...)` (and pass `local` to `MPI_Scatter()`) or declare `point local ;`. In all cases, you should clearly state how many MPI tasks you are running.

Comment: @Zulan thank you, i wasn't thinking that root task is also a receiver so it needs memory for local. Also i forgot to remove the &, i'm an idiot. Now it works, thank you!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet in the working code i didn't state the number of tasks but it works. Why should i declare it inside the code?

Comment: You only need to add your `mpirun` command line to your question. If you run 6 MPI tasks, it might not crash despite a buffer overflow ... an other option is to add an `assert()` and a comment in your code to abort if more than 5 MPI tasks.

Comment: Also, there is `MPI_IN_PLACE` if you do not require a receive buffer on the root rank.